# How to build and flash Pixel 8 platform and kernel

Tags: kernel, google-pixel, aosp

I am a complete newbie to AOSP and I'm having trouble building and flashing android kernel for Pixel 8.

I've been trying to follow [Building Pixel Kernels](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels) instructions, but I'm experiencing some issues. I think my problem is that **I don't know which platform manifest branch to use with which kernel manifest branch.**

- When I try to [flash the device using flash.android.com](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels#flash_the_device_using_flashandroidcom), there are no instructions on which platform and kernel combination is supported for Pixel 8 device (there's [a table](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels#supported-kernel-branches) but it only has information regarding Pixel 6). I tried flashing `git-aosp-main-with-phones`, but after flashing the kernel, Pixel 8 will not boot correctly. I built the kernel by repo init & sync -ing `android-gs-shusky-5.15-android14-d1` branch from android kernel manifest. I followed [the guide](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels#download_and_compile_the_kernel) from the same instructions mentioned above for fetching kernel source, building it, and flashing it. But the device only displays android logo and after a few minutes, kernel panics.
- I decided to try fetching and building the platform myself, and I tried following combinations:

  - platform manifest `android-14.0.0_r27` and kernel manifest `android-gs-shusky-5.15-android14-d1`

    - results: kernel panics after a couple of minutes
  - platform manifest `android-14.0.0_r6` and kernel manifest `android-gs-shusky-5.15-android14-qpr1`

    - results: kernel doesn't panic, but Pixel 8 displays Google logo and doesn't proceed

If someone could point me to a working platform and kernel combination for Pixel 8, (or if I'm doing something else wrong) it would be extremely helpful!